# formular in bootstrap modal not processing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

i've got a page movies/add

in this page I tried to use a bootstrap modal with a included form that should call the users/signup function

The form looks like this:

```
   <%= form_for User.new, :html => {:multipart => true, :class => "form-horizontal", :role => "form", :id => "signupform"}, :as => :user, :method => :post, :url => {}, :controller => :users, :action => :signup do |f| %>
```

I don't get an error, it looks like it works fine, but in database there is nothing.

the controller function in useres_controller looks like this:

```
def signup
if request.post?
  puts "SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSs"
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
    flash[:notice] = t("flash.signup")
    #Weiterleitung nach erfolgreichem Anlegen
    redirect_to :controller => :startsites, :action => "index"
  end
else
  @user = User.new
end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code if `@user.save` returns false you don't do anything. The idiom I use looks like this.

```
if @user.save
   flash[:success] = "Welcome"
   redirect_to ...
else
   flash[:error] = "Failed"
   render 'new'
end
```

and render any errors raised by your model within your form.